# Using 'or' condition in jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery

How should I use 'or' in jQuery validation of equal?

For example:

```
reg_fee:{   
   required: true,  
   equalTo: "#membercount"
},
```

This is the normal `equalTo` validation, but I want to use 'or' option in the `equalTo`. 
Could I use it like this?

```
reg_fee:{   
    required: true, 
    equalTo: "#membercount || #ren_membercount"
}
```

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to support it but my first bet would be to use: `equalTo: function(){return this.value === $('#membercount').val() || this.value === $('#ren_membercount').val();}`. You should try that and see...

Comment: Is `#membercount` an element ID? Are you validating against its text value?

Comment: yes #membercount is an element id