# JQuery Validate OR conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm developing an application and I'm having issues with **or conditional** validation using [Jquery Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). I must to validate two formats of one text. Recently I added just **one** custom validation (which is working fine) into `additional-methods.js`:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("format1", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || validateSomething(value); 
}, "Check format 1");
```

And I'm using it this way:

```
$("form[name='myForm']").validate({
    rules: {
        fieldName : {
                required: true,
                format1: true
            }
    },
    messages: {
        fieldName : {
            required: "Please fill something",
            format1: "Please fill with format 1"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
});
```

But i need validate **`(format 1 OR format 2)`**. I searched through docs and SO with no luck. Anybody have done anything like this? Any clue would be welcome!

This question is very similar: [Using 'or' condition in jquery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329201/using-or-condition-in-jquery-validation-plugin)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean that "Format 1" or "Format 2" are just validation rule sets?

Comment: Yes, they are custom validation rules added through additional-methods file (as docs point out).

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from doing something like: `if(condition){ $(...).validate({...}); /* first set of rules */ }else{ $(...).validate({...}); /* second set of rules */ }`, cause I think that's your solution. The `condition` in this case would be whatever is the "OR" case, like, "if [x] input has value" or whatever

Comment: I think that could be an approach, but i wanted to find a more maintainable solution (I'm not the only one in the coding team). Thanks for you suggestion anyway @Aeolingamenfel.

Comment: In what way is this not maintainable? Do the rules shares some core set of rules? That's also easily addable in a way where you don't have to repeat code.

Comment: Yes, this is the minimal example. Both rules have a lot of sharing rules (even some remote validations).

Comment: Would you like me to whip up an example of how to have shared rules? I think this model can still work fairly well.